# Reliably Clean Email Message Body Encoding

Tags: php, encoding, imap

I am writing a small piece of software in php which connects to a IMAP email box and stores the messages contained therein in a MySQL DB for later processing and other goodness.

I have noticed that during testing I get some strange characters appearing in the message body when I attempt to save the message body raw. I am using imap_fetchbody() to extract the message body.

I noticed that when I use quoted_printable_decode() to clean up the message body this helps! However in doing lots of research I have also learned that this will not always help and that other methods such as utf8_encode() and base64_decode() should be used instead to clean up the message body.

So, my question is: what is the best method for reliably cleaning an email message body with php to cover all encoding scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "email body" is nowadays actually a tree of individual MIME parts. Sometimes there's just one of them, e.g. a `text/plain` mail. Sometimes there's a `multipart/alternative` which wraps inside it two "equivalent" copies of the message, one as `text/plain` and other as `text/html`. Sometimes the structure is much more complicated, with many levels of nesting. It is quite common that some of these parts are actually binary content, like images, attached ZIP files and what not.

Each of these individual MIME parts can be *encoded* for transport; these are specified in the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header of the corresponding MIME part. The two encoding schemes which you absolutely must support to interoperate are `quoted-printable` and `base64`. An important observation is that this encoding happens separately for each part, i.e. it's perfectly legal to have a `multipart/alternative` with a `text/plain` encoded with `quoted-printable` and another part, `text/html` encoded in `base64`.

When you have decoded this transfer encoding, you still have to decode the text from its character encoding to Unicode, i.e. to turn the stream of bytes into Unicode text. You need to consult the `encoding` parameter of the `Content-Type` MIME header (again, the part header, not the whole-message header, unless the message itself has only one part).

All details you need to know are in RFC 2045, RFC 2046, RFC 2047 and RFC 2048 (and their corresponding updates).

FInally, there's also the interesting question on what the "main part" of an e-mail is. Suppose you have something like this:

```
1 multipart/mixed
  + 1.1 text/plain: "Hi, I'm forwarding Jeff's message..."
  + 1.2 message/rfc822
    + 1.2.1 multipart/alternative
       + 1.2.1.1 text/plain "Hi coleagues, I'm sending the meeting notes from..."
       + 1.2.1.2 text/html "<p>Hi colleagues,..."
```

i.e. this happens when Fred forwards Jeff's message to you. What is the "main part" here?