# How to decode message with PHP, received from Microsoft Outlook Express 6?

Tags: php, email, imap, decode, orocrm

I have a problem with OroCRM email bundle, when I sync my emails some of them do not decoded properly. In eg. with IMAP I got this message its not decoded now:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dwindows-1257" =
http-equiv=3DContent-Type>
<META name=3DGENERATOR content=3D"MSHTML 8.00.6001.23588">
<STYLE></STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgColor=3D#ffffff>
<DIV><FONT size=3D2 face=3DArial></FONT>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV><FONT size=3D2 face=3DArial></FONT>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV><FONT size=3D2 face=3DArial></FONT>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV><FONT size=3D2 face=3DArial>Administrator=EB</FONT></DIV>
<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV><FONT size=3D2 face=3DArial>Asta Aug=EBnien=EB</FONT></DIV>
<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV><FONT size=3D2 face=3DArial><BR>UAB "Komeksimas"<BR>V. =C8kalovo g. =

20B,<BR>LT-76371 =D0iauliai</FONT></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

after executed `quoted_printable_decode` function I got this result:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1257" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 8.00.6001.23588">
<STYLE></STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgColor=#ffffff>
<DIV><FONT size=2 face=Arial></FONT>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV><FONT size=2 face=Arial></FONT>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV><FONT size=2 face=Arial></FONT>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV><FONT size=2 face=Arial>Administrator�</FONT></DIV>
<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV><FONT size=2 face=Arial>Asta Aug�nien�</FONT></DIV>
<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV><FONT size=2 face=Arial><BR>UAB "Komeksimas"<BR>V. �kalovo g. 
20B,<BR>LT-76371 �iauliai</FONT></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

The true result after function executed have to be this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1257" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 8.00.6001.23588">
<STYLE></STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgColor=#ffffff>
<DIV><FONT size=2 face=Arial></FONT>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV><FONT size=2 face=Arial></FONT>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV><FONT size=2 face=Arial></FONT>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV><FONT size=2 face=Arial>Administratorė</FONT></DIV>
<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV><FONT size=2 face=Arial>Asta Augėnienė</FONT></DIV>
<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>
<DIV><FONT size=2 face=Arial><BR>UAB "Komeksimas"<BR>V. Čkalovo g. 
20B,<BR>LT-76371 Šiauliai</FONT></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

This problem I see just fetching messages that was send from Microsoft Outlook Express 6, from later email client versions I do not get this problem.

Comment: Looks like You are having a problem with default encoding to utf-8 setting, Can you post what is a default setting in your PHP. Or try to override the setting in PHP class. or try with below code just add in you php class `ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding','UTF-8');
ini_set('mbstring.func_overload',7);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`

Comment: This is deprecated :

mbstring.internal_encoding string
Warning
This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.6.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged. My system runs on PHP 5.6+

Comment: The meta header says the email is windows-1257 encoding. Did you use that to decode it?

Comment: In `quoted_printable_decode` function I can't set decode charset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reliably Clean Email Message Body Encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379027/reliably-clean-email-message-body-encoding)